How to remove items from a list type in QML
How can I remove elements from a specified index when a list type does not have a pop() method, a remove() method, or a splice() method.
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    property  list<QtObject> arr:[
        QtObject{
            property real a: 1.0
        },
        QtObject{
            property real a: 1.0
        },
        QtObject{

        },
        QtObject{

        }
    ]

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(arr.length)
        arr.remove(1)//error：TypeError: Property 'remove' of object [object Object] is not a function
        console.log(arr.length)
    }
}


Using list<var> instead of list<QtObject> enables more JavaScript methods like splice, pop, push, and sort, leading to increased utility.
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: arr
        property list<var> arr:[
            { a: 1.1 },
            { a: 2.2 }, // item to remove
            { a: 3.3 },
            { a: 4.4 }
        ]
        delegate: ItemDelegate { text: modelData.a }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            arr.splice(1,1); // remove item at index 1
            arr.pop(); // remove last item
            arr.push( {a: 5.5 } ); // append to list
            arr.sort((i,j) => -(i.a - j.a)); // sort descending
        }
    }

You can Try the list-var solution online
Continuing with list<QtObject> will limit your access to JavaScript methods. Only basic list functionality is enabled, and as per the documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-list.html), the sole method to truncate the list is by decrementing the length property.
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: arr
        property list<QtObject> arr:[
            QtObject { property real a: 1.1 },
            QtObject { property real a: 2.2 }, // item to remove
            QtObject { property real a: 3.3 },
            QtObject { property real a: 4.4 }
        ]
        delegate: ItemDelegate { text: modelData.a }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            // remove item at index 1
            arr[1] = arr[2];
            arr[2] = arr[3];
            arr.length--;
        }
    }

You can Try the list-QtObject solution online
Note that, not only list<var> works, but, also other types that are native to Javascript. For instance, we can make it work with list<real>:
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: arr
        property list<real> arr:[
            1.1,
            2.2, // item to remove
            3.3,
            4.4
        ]
        delegate: ItemDelegate { text: modelData }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            arr.splice(1,1); // remove item at index 1
            arr.pop(); // remove last item
            arr.push( 5.5 ); // append to list
            arr.sort((i,j) => -(i.a - j.a)); // sort descending
        }
    }

You can Try the list-real solution online

You define a JavaScript list, so splice should work:
arr.splice(1, 1)


bruh this is not javascript array, it's qml list type

To clarify, splice() functions properly but exclusively with list<var>, not list<QtObject>.
